# I get a PayPal Error while trying to login

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

everyone I integrated the **PayPal API** but I have a problem, every time I press log in and I insert my **PayPal** account(I create a sandbox with the business **PayPal** account ) it gives me an ***error: Username or password is incorrect*** and I can't understand why since I log in with that credentials into my account.

Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? The first time I'm doing this. Thank you in advance.

**Code :**

```
package com.example.ipill;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalConfiguration;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPayment;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmation;

import org.json.JSONException;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.net.HttpCookie;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  OnRemoveItemClickListener{

    private TextView total;
    private ImageButton removeFromCartt;
    private Button pay;
    private RecyclerView mResultList2;
    private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;

    public int Totalprice;
    private UsersAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Users_get> array_data = new ArrayList<>();
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    public static final int PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE = 7171;

    private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
            .environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
            .clientId(Config.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);
        mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cart");

        total          = findViewById(R.id.TotalPrice);
        total.setText(0+"");
        removeFromCartt = findViewById(R.id.removeFromCart);
        mResultList2    = findViewById(R.id.cartList);
        pay            = findViewById(R.id.pay);

        mResultList2.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mResultList2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        Intent intent = new Intent (this,PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
        startService(intent);

        // Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
        mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                int flag=1;

                if (adapter == null) {

                    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Users_get post = childSnapshot.getValue(Users_get.class);
                        array_data.add(new Users_get(post.getName(), post.getSurname(), post.getPrice(), childSnapshot.getKey()));
                        getTotalPrice(post.getPrice(),flag);
                        total.setText(Totalprice+"");
                    }

                    setAdapter();
                } else {

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
            }

        });


        pay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                processPayment();
            }
        });

    }

    private void processPayment() {
        PayPalPayment payPalPayment =  new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(Totalprice)),"EUR",
                "Make the payment",PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
        Intent intent = new Intent (CartActivity.this,PaymentActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT,payPalPayment);
        startActivityForResult(intent,PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                PaymentConfirmation confirmation = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                if (confirmation != null) {
                    try {
                        String paymenDetails = confirmation.toJSONObject().toString(4);
                        startActivity(new Intent(this, PaymentDetails.class)
                                .putExtra("PaymentDetails", paymenDetails)
                                .putExtra("PaymentAmount", Totalprice));

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else if (requestCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void setAdapter() {
        adapter = new UsersAdapter(array_data,CartActivity.this);
        mResultList2.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public void getTotalPrice(Long price,int flag){
            if(flag==1)
            {
                Totalprice+=price;
            }
            else {
                Totalprice-=price;
            }
        System.out.println(Totalprice);
    }


    @Override
    public void onRemoveItemClicked(final int position) {
        int flag=0;
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cart").child(array_data.get(position).getKey()).removeValue();
        getTotalPrice(array_data.get(position).getPrice(),flag);
        total.setText(Totalprice+"");
        array_data.remove(position);
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        stopService(new Intent(this,PayPalService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
        if(adapter !=null){
            adapter.removeListener();
        }
    }
}
```

**Second activity :**

```
package com.example.ipill;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class PaymentDetails extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView txtID, txtStatus,txtAmount;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment_details);

        txtID = findViewById(R.id.txtID);
        txtAmount= findViewById(R.id.txtAmount);
        txtStatus=findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        try{
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(intent.getStringExtra("PaymentDetails"));
            showDetails(jsonObject.getJSONObject("response"),intent.getStringExtra("PaymentAmount"));
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void showDetails(JSONObject response, String PaymentAmount) {
        try {
            txtID.setText(response.getString("id"));
            txtStatus.setText(response.getString("state"));
            txtAmount.setText("$"+PaymentAmount);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting :

```
 E/paypal.sdk: request failure with http statusCode:401,exception:
E/paypal.sdk: request failed with server response:{"error":"invalid_user","error_description":"Invalid user credentials"}
E/paypal.sdk: invalid_user
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you are using a deprecated Android SDK that is no longer supported. If you need a native SDK, use PayPal Express Checkout via Braintree: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/accept-payments/express-checkout/ec-braintree-sdk/get-started/

Also make sure the credentials you are using to log in with in Sandbox mode work at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com